# With the new openGL driver, can I make a resolution change permanent?

Tags: hdmi, screen, xorg, opengles

I am using the new openGL driver to run a WebGL app. It runs a lot smoother if I change resolution to 720p, which I can do with

```
xrandr -s 1280x720
```

This works perfect, but resets after reboot. I have tried making a ~/.xprofile file which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
xrandr -s 1280x720
```

The file has execute permissions, but the resolution remains at native 1920x1080 when I log in.

Is there a way to make my resolution permanent?

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi corner of the Stack Exchange network. Is that `.xprofile` file actually being run? I must confess I was not previously aware of it but I found this [ArchLinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xprofile) article (not explicitly something for an RPi but it was bit helpful) about the file and it make me wonder there is the lines in the other files to run this command when the X server is started up.  On my RPi (Raspbian, "Jessie", SysV `init`!) I can find no trace of such a file or reference to it... which distribution are you using ("Raspbian" perhap?)

Comment: I am running Raspbian Jessie. I don't know if it is actually being run. .xprofile was something I found while googling the original issue of how to change res on login

Comment: Yeah, it sounds as though the file is not being run - hence the absence of the change it is to provoke - ideally you just need to convince the X server to _start_ in the right mode. Do you think this Foundation Forum topic "[Change default X11 display resolution](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=120484)" has any relevance in your case i.e. to specify a framebuffer size in the `config.txt` file - more detail on that in the [tag:config,txt](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tags/config.txt/info)...

Comment: I tried that but it seems to be ignored when using the new OpenGL driver.

Comment: Just so I can check/get it - what package contains that OpenGL driver or how do I ensure I've got it present (what is the precise name and where will it appear in the system)?

Comment: I don't know. But you enable/disable it from raspi-config > Advanced > GL Driver